# ¿Cómo hago que no se pueda repetir el valor de una String en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Quiero que cuando intentes hacer un INSERT, pero el valor de una variable concreta ya esté registrado, muestre un error.

Por ejemplo:
| usuario | email |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Jose    | jose@apellido.com            |
| Rex   | rex@miperro.com            |

Si introduzco este código debería mostrar un error porque el valor ya está asignado a un usuario.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`usuario`, `email`) VALUES ("Eduardo", "prueba@gmail.com");
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, soy nuevo y esto me serviría de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Todo depende donde queres lograr eso.. en tu front? en un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Es mysql, @gbianchi

Comment: mysql es tu base de datos.. yo no pregunte eso..  porque que tipo de respuesta buscas? una query? modificar tu tabla? un constraint?

Comment: Un query que evite que ya esté escrito ese valor,  
@gbianchi .

Comment: En ese caso deberias hacer una query con `where`  el campo que buscas, y validar en caso de que traiga un resultado o, mas envies un mensaje de alerta al usuario  de que el registro ya existe.

Comment: No hay un insert con where... por eso te preguntaba que querias hacer... si podes poner un constraint a tu tabla para que tire error al insertar.. esto es productivo o un ejercicio?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes pedir primero los datos registrados con **SELECT** para luego comparar los datos ingresados con los registrados y así si se repite alguno de los datos ingresados mostrar un mensaje de que los datos ya existen, y si no pasar a guardar los datos con **INSERT**, como hice a continuación:

```
<?php
     $query = mysqli_query("SELECT 'usuario', 'email' FROM users");
     $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
     $repeat = 0;
    
     if($result > 0)
     {
          while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
          {
               if(hash_equals($data['usuario'], "Eduardo") || hash_equals($data['email'], "elpaspafe@gmail.com")) {
                    $repeat = 1;
                    break;
               }
          }
          if($repeat == 0) {
               $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`usuario`, `email`) VALUES ("Eduardo", "elpaspafe@gmail.com")");
               $sentenciaSQL->execute();
               $data=$sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
          }else {
               echo "Estos datos ya se encuentran registrados.";
          }
     }
?>
```

También puedes hacer un **SELECT** con un **WHERE** para buscar directamente el dato en la tabla:

```
<?php

 $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("SELECT* FROM users WHERE email=:email");
 $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':email','elpaspafe@gmail.com');
 $sentenciaSQL->execute();
 $data=$sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

 if($data['password'] == "elpaspafe@gmail.com")
 {
      echo "Estos datos ya se encuentran registrados.";
 }else {
      $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`usuario`, `email`) VALUES ("Eduardo", "elpaspafe@gmail.com")");
      $sentenciaSQL->execute();
      $data=$sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
      echo "Datos registrados correctamente.";
 }

?>
```

Espero que te sirva ;).

Comment: La respuesta no esta mal.. pero que te hace suponer que es php? mysql es una base de datos, que se puede usar con cualquier lenguaje ;)... en esos casos, siempre esperamos a que aclaren el problema...

Comment: Le pongo el ejemplo en php para que tenga una idea de como lo hago y así pueda hacerlo en su lenguaje, porque tampoco especifica el lenguaje en el que lo está haciendo :)

Comment: Y si solo lo queria en la DB? repito.. no esta mal.. pero puede que directamente no le sirva... en ese caso, esperamos a que clarifique el problema...

Comment: Gracias, sí sirvió. 
Me encanta esta comunidad de Stack Overfolf.